# Dreamweaver CS6/CC hangs or freeze

Tags: dreamweaver, freeze

I am having problems with Dreamweaver hanging/freezes. I have searched the entire internet now without finding an answer related to my problems.

This error is related to every newer version of Dreamweaver (CS5, CS6, CC). 
First it hangs when i start dreamweaver for about 20-30 seconds. After that it starts to hang when i finish writing something. I can write one line then wait 2 seconds and it starts to hang. It also hangs when i save files.

It happens on every kind of file (php, css, html etc).

Everytime it hangs i get (not responding) in the dreamweaver window. It hangs for about 10-20 seconds.

I have been using Dreamweaver for a long time and never had this problem before.

I have tried to delete the cache file without any difference. I have tried various regedit fixes without luck.  I have reinstalled and deleted all kind of preferences. I have disabled "Enable related files". The only remaining option is to format the computer and reinstall everything.

Can someone please help me or give me a hint ?

I am using Windows 7 ultimate 32 bit.

Comment: Wouldn't http://superuser.com/ be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this - it involves a registry edit on Windows to prevent dreamweaver checking the validity of the ip address of any external links in the pages you write:

http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/hang-opening-document-dreamweaver-cs5.html

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I just tried this on mine (Dreamweaver CS6/Win7 64), and it didn't change anything.  The problem seems to be when Dreamweaver is attempting to access remote files, it'll hang forever.  Been having the same issue forever now.

Comment: this worked on CS6 but now on CC its back and this trick is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup Manage Site on Toolbar/Site/Manage Site. Maybe when you open file, the DW will contact with the server and it takes time. When you save file too. You can disconnect to the server and do your job after that you will commit it soon.

To disconnection. Toolbar/Site/Manage Site. Choose your site. Click the Server Tab. Uncheck from box Remote beside box Testing.

If your problem does not like this. You can check the link @user3001950's comment. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function you can set to automatically upload changed files to the remote server.    If you have that set to 'on'  and Dreamweaver is having trouble connecting to the remote server,  that could cause the delay.

It's one of the advanced settings in the set up of the remote server.

Go to `Manage Sites -> sitename -> servers -> remote server -> Advanced`   and then UNCHECK  `Automatically upload files to server on Save`

If that works, then you'll have to upload files manually from time to time.    That's how I recommend you do it anyway, to avoid uploading files that are not 100% hunkydory yet.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Command Prompt as administrator. You need to be in the system32 folder to run this command.

2)Type sfc /scannow

3) Wait for the scan to complete. Restart the computer once.

That'sall

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem and here is a direct answer to your question. Turn off all excess procesess in your windows OS. Here is what have worked for me:

http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-xp-x86-32-bit-service-pack-3-service-configurations/

and DW CS6 became LIGHTING FAST!!! on my machine... (x200s thinkpad downgraded to win xp sp3, you have settings for any win on that site)...

PS: Of course, I'll not mention "ccleaner" and "defragmenter"... bottom line, just do that and you'll become an euphoric user of DW...

PS2: Please, please do not buy a new laptop because that's not a reason in your case... (as some tech bloggers mentioned apro DW CS6 speed issue)...

IMPORTANT: Service config (on site I provided you) which is first safe before "barebones config", I'm working with that config now. Not "barebones", configuration....... BEFORE that is ours in this case. Select radio buttons on author's site services test and under that you have "save" button which will deliver a reg file of your taste for speed not just of DW on your comp but for any demanding software you're running...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it may be weird but i have to say that. My Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015 frozed many times after pasting more than 800 row html code. Then i right clicked Dreamweaver shortcut icon and disabled compability mode and it started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is working, and this is a Dreamweaver design... It's been for years, and it's work perfect while you have small files. A big file is a problem and Dreamweaver never could handle them and never will, because it's an editor for beginners, do small stuff. Don't get me wrong, I love it, but once you have big files to work with, you stuck. I am using this editor only because of FTP, if I would find another editor with this option, I will give a try...

Comment: I performed a search and this is very valid post. I disagree with  comment